# Merging two sorted ArrayLists

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, merge

I am supposed to create a method that will merge two given pre-sorted ArrayLists of Strings into one. All of it has to be done in one loop. The way I have gone about it is comparing the two ArrayLists at each index and adding them in alphabetical order based on those comparisons. The problem with this is that if you are given two ArrayLists ["Bob", "Jill"] and ["Watson", "Zane"], the output would be ["Bob", "Watson", "Jill", "Zane"]. This is clearly not sorted.

That being said, I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to implement a fix for it.

Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> al1, ArrayList<String> al2){
  ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String> (al1.size() + al2.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(al1.size(), al2.size()); i++) { // Loops until max size of the two arraylists is reached
      if (i < al1.size() && i < al2.size()) { // Checks if the index is still in range of both arraylists
          if (al1.get(i).compareTo(al2.get(i)) < 0) { // Compares the two arraylists at the same index
              al.add(al1.get(i));
              al.add(al2.get(i));
          } else {
              al.add(al2.get(i));
              al.add(al1.get(i));
          }
      } else if (i < al1.size() && i > al2.size()) { // Checks if the index is greater than the size of al2
          al.add(al1.get(i));
      } else { // Anything else, just add al2
          al.add(al2.get(i));
      }
  }
  return al;
```

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [merge algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) would be a good start, if you haven't seen that already.

Comment: You're always comparing elements at the same index in the two lists.  That doesn't work at all, as you've found.  You'll need to keep track of separate positions in the two lists of the current elements being being considered for addition to the merged list.  When you come to the end of one list, you'll want to append all the elements of the other to the merged result.

Comment: Technically it's 3 loops of which 2 are used. The merging loop stops when the end of either pre-sorted arraylist is reached, and then a copy loop to copy the rest of the remaining pre-sorted array (assuming Java doesn't have the equivalent of a memcpy or a slice). This could be folded into a single loop using if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<Double> merge(ArrayList<Double> a, ArrayList<Double> b) {

    ArrayList<Double> toReturn = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int a_ = 0;
    int b_ = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < a.size() + b.size(); j++) {
        if(a_ == a.size())
            toReturn.add(b.get(b_++));
        else if(b_ == b.size())
            toReturn.add(a.get(a_++));
        else if(a.get(a_).compareTo(b.get(b_)) < 0)
            toReturn.add(a.get(a_++));
        else
            toReturn.add(b.get(b_++));
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using one index, `i`, to index into both `a1` and `a2`, which means that you can't move through the two lists independently. As you've noticed, a pair of lists like `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]` should be merged by taking all three elements from the first list and *then* taking the elements from the second list. By traversing both lists simultaneously as you're doing that's not possible.

Instead track two separate indicies, say `i1` and `i2`, and increment them independently. At each iteration determine which index is smaller, add that value and increment that index. Once you've reached the end of one list or the other you just drain the remaining list.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud take a look at merge step of merge-sort algo:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

All in all you should have something like:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i < a.size() && j < b.size()) {
    if (a.get(i).compareTo(b.get(j)) <= 0) {
        result.add(a.get(i));
        ++i;
    } else {
        result.add(b.get(j));
        ++j;
    }
}

for (; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    result.add(a.get(i));
}

for (; j < a.size(); ++j) {
    result.add(b.get(j));
}

return result;
```

Didin't test it, however in result you should have something that looks the same